# Java Server using Jetty: Very simple example does not work, displays HTTP ERROR 503 Service Unavailable

Tags: java, xml, server, jetty

I have been following this tutorial: https://happycoding.io/tutorials/java-server/servlets

Displaying a static html webpage was fine, however I can't get the dynamic version to work.
My web.xml is as follows:

```
<web-app>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>MyHelloWorldServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>HelloWorldServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>MyHelloWorldServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/index.html</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

My java code is as follows:

```
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

public class HelloWorldServlet extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        out.println("<h1>Hello world!</h1>");
        out.println("<p>This is our first servlet.</p>");
    }
}
```

I have compiled the java code in BlueJ and added the .class file to a classes folder in WEB-INF.
My file order is as follows:
webapps/
HelloWorldWebApp/
WEB-INF/
web.xml
classes/
HelloWorldServlet.class

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: 503 means the webapp didn't deploy.  Can you edit your question and add how you compile, and how you run jetty, and also any output / errors from running jetty that you see?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the problem.

The browser was only displaying the 503 error, but the terminal from which I had started the server was actually displaying more error information. The error was that the current version of jdk I was using was not compatible with jetty. I couldn't figure out how to change the java version in bluej, so instead I just downloaded se 8 and compiled through the command line. This fixed the problem.